# How to push a block to the bottom of another block?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I know this may be a trivial question, but how do I push a block to the bottom edge of another block, preferably without changing the structure?

I want the `product__image-background` block and `product__title` to be pushed to the top of the card, and the `product__buy` block to the bottom of the card.

**Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data/data.json';
import './Product.css';

function Product() {
        return (
            <div className='block'>
                {data.map((el) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='product' key={el.id}>
                            <div className='product__image-background'>
                                <img className='product__image' src={el.img}></img>
                            </div>
                            <h3 className='product__title'>{el.title}</h3>
                            <div className='product__buy'>
                                <h3 className='product__buy-price'>{el.price} грн</h3>
                                <button className='product__buy-button'>В корзину</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>c
        )
}

export default Product;
```

CSS:

```
.product__buy {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

If you still need to change the internal structure of the card, what is the best way to do this?

The cards should look like this:

[image: Card]

But some look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach your expected output ?

Comment: @Arjun added examples

Comment: Does `.product__buy {margin-top:auto;}` work?

Comment: @IvanBeliakov no